# Airflow - how can I get data from a BigQuery table and use it as a list?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to get a column, then use values to create file names.

I've tried the following, which should create a csv with the name of the first value in the column specified. It says the list is empty though when I try to use it

```
bq_data = []
get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
    task_id='get_data_from_bq',
    dataset_id='SK22',
    table_id='current_times',
    max_results='100',
    selected_fields='current_timestamps',
)


def process_data_from_bq(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    global bq_data
    bq_data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data_from_bq')


process_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_data_from_bq',
        python_callable=process_data_from_bq,
        provide_context=True)
run_export = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id=f"save_data_on_storage{str(bq_data[0])}",
        source_project_dataset_table="a-data-set",
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=[f"gs://europe-west1-airflow-bucket/data/test{bq_data[0]}.csv"],
        export_format="CSV",
        field_delimiter=",",
        print_header=False,
        dag=dag,
    )

get_data >> process_data >> run_export
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no need to use a `PythonOperator` between `BigQueryGetDataOperator` and `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator`, you can directly use `xcom pull` in `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` :

```py
get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
    task_id='get_data_from_bq',
    dataset_id='SK22',
    table_id='current_times',
    max_results='100',
    selected_fields='current_timestamps',
)

run_export = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id="save_data_on_storage",
        source_project_dataset_table="a-data-set",
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=[f"gs://europe-west1-airflow-bucket/data/test" + "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data_from_bq')[0] }}" + ".csv"],
        export_format="CSV",
        field_delimiter=",",
        print_header=False,
        dag=dag,
    )

get_data >> run_export
```

`destination_cloud_storage_uris` is a [templated](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html) param and you can pass `Jinja` template syntax inside.

I don't tested the syntax but it should work.

I also don't recommend you using global variable like `bq_data` to pass data between operators, because it doesn't work, you need to find a way to use `xcom` directly in the operator (`Jinja` template or access to the current `Context` of the operator).

I also noticed that you are not using the latest `Airflow` operators :

- BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator -> [BigQueryToGCSOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html)

**If you want using all the list provided by BigQueryGetDataOperator operator and calculate a list of destination URIs from it, I propose you another solution** :

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import List, Dict, Sequence

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToGCSOperator
from google.cloud.bigquery import DEFAULT_RETRY
from urllib3 import Retry


class CustomBigQueryToGCSOperator(BigQueryToGCSOperator):

    def __init__(self,
                 source_project_dataset_table: str,
                 project_id: str | None = None,
                 compression: str = "NONE",
                 export_format: str = "CSV",
                 field_delimiter: str = ",",
                 print_header: bool = True,
                 gcp_conn_id: str = "google_cloud_default",
                 delegate_to: str | None = None,
                 labels: dict | None = None,
                 location: str | None = None,
                 impersonation_chain: str | Sequence[str] | None = None,
                 result_retry: Retry = DEFAULT_RETRY,
                 result_timeout: float | None = None,
                 job_id: str | None = None,
                 force_rerun: bool = False,
                 reattach_states: set[str] | None = None,
                 deferrable: bool = False,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        super(CustomBigQueryToGCSOperator, self).__init__(
            source_project_dataset_table=source_project_dataset_table,
            destination_cloud_storage_uris=[],
            project_id=project_id,
            compression=compression,
            export_format=export_format,
            field_delimiter=field_delimiter,
            print_header=print_header,
            gcp_conn_id=gcp_conn_id,
            delegate_to=delegate_to,
            labels=labels,
            location=location,
            impersonation_chain=impersonation_chain,
            result_retry=result_retry,
            result_timeout=result_timeout,
            job_id=job_id,
            force_rerun=force_rerun,
            reattach_states=reattach_states,
            deferrable=deferrable,
            **kwargs
        )

    def execute(self, context):
        task_instance = context['task_instance']
        data_from_bq: List[Dict] = task_instance.xcom_pull('get_data_from_bq')

        destination_cloud_storage_uris: List[str] = list(map(self.to_destination_cloud_storage_uris, data_from_bq))

        self.destination_cloud_storage_uris = destination_cloud_storage_uris

        super(CustomBigQueryToGCSOperator, self).execute(context)

    def to_destination_cloud_storage_uris(self, data_from_bq: Dict) -> str:
        return f"gs://europe-west1-airflow-bucket/data/test{data_from_bq['your_field']}.csv"
```

Example of instantiation of this operator (without `destination_cloud_storage_uris` field because it's calculated inside the operator):

```py
CustomBigQueryToGCSOperator(
    task_id="save_data_on_storage",
    source_project_dataset_table="airflow-proj.source_table.attribute_table",
    export_format="CSV",
    field_delimiter=","
)
```

Some explanations :

- I created a custom operator that extends `BigQueryToGCSOperator`
- In the `execute` method, I have access to the current context of the operator
- From the context, I can retrieve the list from `BQ` provided by the `BigQueryGetDataOperator`. I assume it's a list of Dict but you have to confirm this
- I calculate a list of destination `GCS` URIs from this list of Dict
- I assign the calculated destination `GCS` URIs to the corresponding field in the operator

The pros of this solution, you have more flexibility to apply logic based on xcom value.

The cons is it's little verbose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That seems to work. What is the easiest way of converting this into a list to loop over?

Comment: You want a loop on a the list provided by `get_data_from_bq` instead of taken only the first element in the list ?

Comment: I do if possible, so I can loop through a table and insert data depending on which data is in the table. So I get data from a table, if row 1 contains a value I insert some data to table 1, if row 2 contains certain data I insert data to table 2

Comment: I edited my answer with an example using the all the list provided by the `BQ get` operator. My solution shows how to write a custom operator and calculate a list of `GCS` uri from this list.

Comment: Mostly! I don't suppose you could show me the correct way to call this? I'm calling it like this:
        send_data = CustomBigQueryToGCSOperator(task_id="save_data_on_storage",source_project_dataset_table="airflow-proj.source_table.attribute_table",
            destination_cloud_storage_uris=["gs://europe-west1-airflow-b60259a2-bucket/data/test.csv"],
            export_format="CSV",
            field_delimiter=",",)
However I can't quite get this to work, it throws up an error that "('NoneType' object is not iterable; 32860)".
Apologies for the questions, and thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you have a place in the operator where you expect an iterable but you have None instead. Also in my example `CustomBigQueryToGCSOperator`, I don't pass the param `destination_cloud_storage_uris` because it's calculated in the execute method.

Comment: I added a correction in my answer for the custom operator with fields in the constructor. The `destination_cloud_storage_uris` should not be passed in the operator because it's calculated inside the operator.

Comment: Apologies, one more error. When I run it I get the following error: "airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: missing keyword arguments 'destination_cloud_storage_uris', 'source_project_dataset_table'". I'm running Python 3.7, so it may be due to that? I'm running the class exactly as you are:
    send_data = CustomBigQueryToGCSOperator(
        task_id="save_data_on_storage",
        source_project_dataset_table="project.airflow-dataset.airflow-table",
        export_format="CSV",
        field_delimiter=","
    )

And then run it with "run_base >> send_data"

Comment: Sorry I added a correction.
The current operator is correctly instantiated in an unit test, but I don't tested it in at runtime in Airflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It compiles now, the only issue i have is the following:
    return f"gs://europe-west1-airflow-bucket/data/{data_from_bq['my-table']}.csv"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any idea on a good fix for this? Thanks for the patience, very new to Python!

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, I realised what I was really trying to do was have dynamic stages in a DAG (hence why I was looking at using this as a list). I solved the issue by creating a function that uses the standard BQ client to get a column and parse it as a list, which I then call in the relevant stages in the dag with the expand function built into BQ. Originally I was looking at just getting the first row of a column, but this was the first stage of what I was trying to do, so the other very detailed and well written answer more than answers this question.